# Ajax response returning entire html rather than echo value when on live server, works as expected on local environment

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I know this type of question has been asked here before, but I have tried the proposed solutions to no avail. I have been trying to figure this out for days, but I am truly stumped. Help!
I have a form being processed with php via ajax.  In the php file I echo a response that is then supposed to populate a div on the page.  On my local environment, this works as expected. However, on my live server, instead of the echoed string, ajax returns the entirety of the html on my index.php page.  I cannot figure out why this is happening.  Code:

index.php:

```
<!-- index.php -->
<?php include("partials/header.php"); 
    include("functions/register.php"); 
    include("functions/invitefriend.php"); ?>

<!-- ...preceding html.... -->

<!-- Invite a friend form modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" id="emailFriend" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Share with a friend or colleague via email: </h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="loginForm" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="formRefer">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fromName">Your full name: </label> <span id="fromNameFeedback"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fromName" id="fromName" placeholder="Your full name" required autofocus="true">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="fromEmail">Your email: </label> <span id="fromEmailFeedback"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="fromEmail" id="fromEmail" placeholder="Your email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="toName">Your friend's name: </label> <span id="toNameFeedback"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="toName" id="toName" placeholder="Your friend's name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="toEmail">Your friend's email: </label> <span id="toEmailFeedback"></span>
                        <input class="form-control" type="email" name="toEmail" id="toEmail" placeholder="Your friend's email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                        <p>This person is a: </p>
                      <label class="btn btn-info active">
                        <input type="radio" name="relationship" id="friend" value="friend" autocomplete="off" checked>Friend
                      </label>
                      <label class="btn btn-info">
                        <input type="radio" name="relationship" id="colleague" value="colleague" autocomplete="off">Colleague
                      </label>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="message2" class="questions"><?php echo $message2; ?> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <div id="message3" class="questions"> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <input class="btn btn-info loginlogin loginBtn" type="submit" name="send" id="referSubmitButton" value="Send" href="javascript:void(0)">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
<?php include("partials/footer.php"); ?>
```

invitefriend.php:

```
<?php
//require PHPMailer and autoload
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

//Invite a friend via email form handler
$fromName = strip_tags($_POST["fromName"]);
$fromEmail = strip_tags($_POST["fromEmail"]);
$toName = strip_tags($_POST["toName"]);
$toEmail = strip_tags($_POST["toEmail"]);
// $emailMsg = $_POST["emailMsg"];
$relationship = $_POST["relationship"];
$message2 = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    //Validate form
    $err = false;
    //fromEmail cannot be empty or invalid
    if(array_key_exists("fromEmail", $_POST) && PHPMailer::validateAddress($_POST["fromEmail"])){
        $fromEmail = strip_tags($_POST["fromEmail"]);
    } else {
        $err = true;
        echo "<h3>You must provide a valid email address for yourself.</h3>";
    }
    if(array_key_exists("toEmail", $_POST) && PHPMailer::validateAddress($_POST["toEmail"])){
        $toEmail = strip_tags($_POST["toEmail"]);
    } else {
        $err = true;
        echo "<h3>You must provide a valid email address for your friend or colleague.</h3>";
    }
    if(!$err){
        // Insert emails into db (new table for referral addresses)
        $query = "INSERT INTO invitees (`toName`, `toEmail`, `fromName`, `fromEmail`, `date`) VALUES ('".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $toName)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $toEmail)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fromName)."', '".mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $fromEmail)."', CURDATE())";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);      
        //and send the email using PHPMailer
        $mail = new PHPMailer();

            //Server settings
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;            
            $mail->isSMTP();                                     
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;   
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.stackmail.com';  
            $mail->Username = 'invite@heal-the-nation.com';                
            $mail->Password = 'PMQP1RCngk';                    
            $mail->Port = 587;                                     

            //Recipients
            $mail->setFrom('invite@heal-the-nation.com', 'Heal the Nation');
            $mail->addAddress($toEmail);     // Add a recipient  

            $mail->addReplyTo($fromEmail, $fromName);
            // $mail->addCC('cc@example.com');

            //Add an image in the email body
            $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('./img/HTN_Logo.png', 'HTN_Logo');

            $msg = ''; //Many, many lines of an html email

//Content
            $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
            $mail->Subject = 'An invitation to learn about Heal the Nation: The Healthcare Workers\' Network';
            $mail->Body    = $msg;
            $mail->AltBody = strip_tags($msg);

        if(!$mail->send()) {
            echo "<h3 class='bg-danger text-info'>Unable to send invitation. Please try again.</h3><br>";
            echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            //exit();
        } else {
            echo "<h3 class='bg-success text-info'>Invitation sent!</h3>";
            //exit();
        }   
    }
};

?>
```

invitefriend.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var formRefer = $("#formRefer")
    var fromName = $("#fromName").val();
    var fromEmail = $("#fromEmail").val();
    var toName = $("#toName").val();
    var toEmail = $("#toEmail").val();

formRefer.submit(function(event){

        event.preventDefault();

        showSpinner();
        disableButton();

        var fromName = $("#fromName").val();
        var fromEmail = $("#fromEmail").val();
        var toName = $("#toName").val();
        var toEmail = $("#toEmail").val();

        var formData = $(formRefer).serialize();
        var url = $(formRefer).attr('action');

    $.ajax({
            url:url,
            data:formData,
            type:'POST',
            dataType:"text",
        }).done(function(response){
                console.log(response);
                console.log(response.responseText);             

                if($.trim(response) == "<h3 class='bg-danger text-info'>Unable to send invitation. Please try again.</h3><br>"){
                    console.log("The response says unable to send invite....");
                    $("#message3").html(response);
                } else if($.trim(response) == "<h3 class='bg-success text-info'>Invitation sent!</h3>") {
                    console.log("Success!!!");
                    $("#message3").html(response);
                    //Clear the form...

        }).fail(function(data){      
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.responseText);

                if (data.responseText !== '') {
                    $("#message3").text(data.responseText);
                } else {
                    $("#message3").text('Oops! An error occurred.');
                }
        }); //end ajax request
    }); //end formRefer.submit() function
}); //end document.ready function
```

So on my local environment, when I process this form, my console.log(response) gives me the form data (fromName: John, fromEmail: john@john.com, etc.), and the console.log(response.responseText) gives me the appropriate echo value from the php (either "`<h3 class='bg-danger text-info'>Unable to send invitation. Please try again.</h3>`" or "`<h3 class='bg-success text-info'>Invitation sent!</h3>`"), and this responseText populates the div on the page.

However, when I try this on my live server, it behaves differently.  The console.log(response) returns the entire index.php html content, and the console.log(response.responseText) returns 'undefined' and the div on the page remains empty.  Why????  I know the form is indeed being processed by php because the data is inserted into the database and the email is sent.  So it must be my ajax.  I have tried many things suggested on here and elsewhere but none have worked.  Please help!  Thank you!!

Comment: This generally happens when there happens to be an error and the php system throws a default error page. Copy the entire html response in a textfile and read it to check if there is any error. Secondly, it would be better if you return the status message as json and then parse it into the html using jquery.

Comment: Thank you. I checked the html response and there is no error within it that I can find.  I've re-written some code to parse JSON from php to jquery, but I think I'm having a problem with JSON not being returned as JSON, rather HTML, as I keep getting the error "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".  It is returning my index.html instead of php.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out.  It was indeed an error in my php code.  Turns out my file path to phpmailer 'vendor/autoload' was written incorrectly (I needed to write ../vendor/autoload).  That was the error.  Once I fixed my file path, everything started working perfectly!  So strange that the error reporting wouldn't simply tell me it couldn't find 'vendor/autoload'.